# Interactive PDF with filtering capability

Tags: pdf, reporting, interactive

I need to figure out a way to create an interactive PDF where output table will display values only related to filter chosen.

Example:

Filter: Country choice (U.S., Germany, France)

Data table output when "U.S." is selected in the filter:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|  Ctry | Yr 1 | Yr 2 | Yr 3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
|  U.S. | $10M | $15M | $20M |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Data table output when "Germany" is selected:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|  Ctry | Yr 1 | Yr 2 | Yr 3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
|Germany| $1M  | $1M  | $2M  |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Main argument for not using Excel pivots - not all end users may have MS Office. 
Storing every country report in a single PDF - report becomes too busy when there more than 10 countries.

I got as far as finding some links on PDF with javascript, which may help accomplish the task, although not sure where to start.

My main questions are:

- Can I create such interactive PDFs at all?
- Are there tools that can create PDFs like that with little coding effort (I am not a developer)?
- are there any tools/methods aside from Tableau that can help me create ready-to-use reports (even if not PDF)), but will allow similar user experience I described above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the data part of he document, or from where does the data come?

Comment: A very limited amount of dynamic behavior can be achieved but pdf basically is a format for static contents.

Comment: The data is stored in SQL, but not sure if adding live data source to final report is the way to go, since connection will be broken once report is deliverd to end users without access to DB. Alternatively, I was thinking of what mkl said, since PDF is static, is there a way to add each country report into PDF as hidden page, and revel it only when filter is selected, while hiding all other pages?

Comment: *"as hidden page"* - either as hidden page or as disabled optional content group. Both is possible.

Comment: @mkl would I need Adobe Pro to create reports with hidden pages/disabled groups? (I assume so). Do you happen to have any tutorials/articles on the topic that you can share? I'd appreciate it

Comment: *"would I need Adobe Pro"* - No. Stack overflow is a site for *programming* issues. Any decent general purpose PDF library should allow you to *implement* a PDF creator using optional content groups or page templates to achieve something like that.

Comment: Why not save as HTML complete with js datatable for filter and search.. All of us have browsers. This really should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

That's just not possible in pure PDF. However, if you use a Rich Media Annotation in the PDF, you can create a Flash-based widget that would do what you want but then the PDF would only function in Adobe Acrobat or Reader and only if the Flash player were also installed.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Do you have any good resource to read up on the Rich Media Annotation...I'm doing more research, but will appreciate if you have something effective handy. Cheers.